# ng click in button dont logout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a system to idle a user after 1 minute and I'm opening a modal with a button to alert the user with a button inside which redirects to login page.

```
    controllerScope.logout = function () {
                alert("logout");
                $location.path('/');
                AuthService.logout(controllerScope.user).then(function (result) {
                    $state.go('user.signin');
                });
            };
```

In my view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
<div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Oh, Snap! You've Timed Out!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
            You were idle too long.  Click the button below to be redirected to the login page and begin again.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" ng-click="doLogout()">Back To Login</button>
        </div>
</script>
```

Why when I click on my `"back to login"` on modal it doesn't go to my function on the controller? I tried to pop up an alert, a simple thing but event that doesn't work

Comment: Do you using `controllerAs` syntax?

Comment: Yes, I use

app.controller('InventoryController',['$scope', '$modal', 'AuthService', 'HelperService', '$document', '$state',  function ($scope, $modal, AuthService, HelperService, $document, $state) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;

Comment: firstly it should be like `var controllerScope = this;` and also in view you should use `controlerAs` variable. like this. `ng-click="controllerScope.doLogout()"`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YYfbQqYKrH0fY4UrEueY?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1):

You need to make below changes, since you use `controller as` syntax :

1. In controller it should be like `var controllerScope = this`
2. In HTML controller declaration be like : `ng-controller ="yourcontrollername as controllerScope"`
3. During calling `logout`, it should be like `ng-click="controllerScope.logout()"`

**Update**

Your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYfbQqYKrH0fY4UrEueY?p=preview) has many issues, this even doesn't run angular.
So I created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fancg0cn/) with minimal possible code to show the things to be done.

In general :

> use controller as alias., for logout `ng-click="inventoryCtrl.openNewDeviceModal()"` and for opening modal popup use alias as well `controller: 'InventoryController as inventoryCtrl',`

Comment: I have uploaded my code to share with you https://cg6.tutorialspoint.com/share/206/WyZA3A0x

Comment: Can you try to open now? I think now you can see the code

Comment: @CatiaMatos: still not able to see anything.

Comment: @CatiaMatos: Your plunker has many issues, this even not  running angular, I 've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fancg0cn/) with minimal cpossible code to show you things to be., I'm updating the answer further for this fiddle

Comment: I made a few changes but I'm stuck ... https://plnkr.co/edit/YYfbQqYKrH0fY4UrEueY?p=catalogue

Comment: I don't see any changes in your plunker , I suggest to make changes in my fiddle and then map with your code., or reproduce same in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

**Your `ng-click` method is wrongly called:** Kindly change `ng-click="controllerScope.logout()">` instead of `ng-click="doLogout()">`

### Update

> I have uploaded my code to share with you https://jsfiddle.net/y0xrgjaf/
>      Your template code in outside of the controller div tag. You should add your all html code inside of the main div

```
<div ng-controller="controllername">
   //all code should be here 
</div>
```

---

Copy this below code and paste it

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="InventoryController as inventoryCtrl" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel mb25">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table mb0 table-striped datatable" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="devicesData">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>S/N</th>
                            <th>IP</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Manufacturer</th>
                            <th>Model</th>  
                            <th>Organization</th>   
                            <th style="width:70px;"></th>                       
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openNewDeviceModal()">Add Device</button>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="newDeviceModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" ng-bind="deviceModalTitle"> Add Device</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal bordered-group" role="form" name="addDeviceForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="newdevice.data.name" required>
                    <span ng-show="addDeviceForm.name.$invalid">The name is required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">S/N</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sn" ng-model="newdevice.data.sn" required>
                    <span ng-show="addDeviceForm.sn.$invalid">The S/N is required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="newdevice.device_type_id" ng-options="type.id as type.model for type in deviceTypes">  
                        <option value="">None</option>                      
                    </select>                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Organization</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="newdevice.organization_id" ng-options="organization.id as organization.data.name for organization in organizations">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                    </select>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="saveDevice()" ng-disabled="addDeviceForm.name.$invalid || addDeviceForm.sn.$invalid">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
<div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Oh, Snap! You've Timed Out!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
            You were idle too long.  Click the button below to be redirected to the login page and begin again.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" ng-click="inventoryCtrl.logout()">Back To Login</button>
        </div>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, i rename the function to be sure that wanst conflicting with the logout function of headerController:

app.controller('HeaderController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$http', '$timeout', 'AuthService',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $http, $timeout, AuthService) {

            var controllerScope = $scope;

            controllerScope.logout = function () {
                AuthService.logout(controllerScope.user).then(function (result) {
                    $state.go('user.signin');
                });
            };

Comment: change `var controllerScope = this;` instead of `var controllerScope = $scope`

Comment: I have uploaded my code to share with you https://cg6.tutorialspoint.com/share/206/WyZA3A0x

Comment: I have added here ; just copy and past the html code : https://cg6.tutorialspoint.com/share/206/WyZA3A0x

Comment: Cant see your modifications.. :\

Comment: Have you uploaded your code changes? @Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: Same thing.. nothing changed after i put the html code inside <div> </div>

Comment: I am saying your all code are should be inside of the  `<div ng-controller="InventoryController as inventoryCtrl"> //code</div>`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YYfbQqYKrH0fY4UrEueY?p=catalogue

It's what I've done

Comment: Your controller is fired?

Comment: Can you raise your problem in plunkr?

Comment: My problem is when i pop up the modal after 1 minute of idle... i click on the button "back to login" and the function logout isnt activated.

Comment: When I click the add new button on the `plunkr` it does not opened. because your controller  does not hit. So I couldn't found the real problem

Answer (score 0):

You set doLogout() function into your ng-click. Would you mean logout() as in your controller ?